# deleting folders recursively using windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder with multiple subfolders under it. I would like to delete all test folders under the subfolders/example. How can I do this using windows batch script? Note that there is no test folder in some.

I know how to delete mainfolder/subfolder1/example/test. But am stuck with recursively deleting under each subfolder i.e delete mainfolder/*/example/test.

TIA

E.g:

```
mainfolder
  subfolder1
        source
        example
           test
  subfolder2
       source
       example
           test
  subfolderX
       source
       example
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers... I chose the one as the answer where I didn't have to make any tweaks to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /r "c:\sourcedir" /d %a in (*) do if /i "%~nxa"=="test" echo rd /s /q "%a"
```

direct from the prompt - double each `%` to use as a batch line.

replace `c:\sourcedir` as appropriate

required `rd` is merely `echo`ed to show what he script intends to do. Remove the `echo` keyword after testing to actually perform the deletion.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend looking at [ss64.com's CMD.EXE reference](https://ss64.com/nt/), specifically the [`DIR`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html), [`FINDSTR`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), and [`FOR`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) commands.

```
for /f %i in ('dir /s /a:d /b ^| findstr /i /e "example\test"') do rmdir /s %i
```

appears to be the appropriate command for what you have requested.

Notes on `DIR`: /S - Subdirectories, /A:D - directories only ("Attribute:Directory"), /B - "bare", no headers or footers, just the full pathname.

Notes on `FINDSTR`: /I - Case-insensitive, /E - Match at end-of-string

Verbose descriptive summary of command: Create a list of directories, including all subdirectories, and select only those that end in "example\test", then remove each of them, including all files and subdirectories in them.

Answer (score 2):

```
for /R "mainfolder" /D %%a in (example\te?t) do rd /S "%a"
```

The only inconvenient of this method is that the name of the target folder *must* be given as a wild-card, so you must give a name that does not include any other undesired folder. If the name is given with no wild-card, the `for` command may include other folders.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to iterate through the main directories, and check for the existence of the directory that you want to delete:

```
for /D %%d in (mainfolder\*) do if exist "%%d\example\test" rd /s /q "%%d\example\test"
```