# Windows-Batch: How to write a nested for loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

I have the following directory structure:

```
WebERP
  --DDL
    --file1.sql
    --file2.sql
  --DML
    --file1.sql
    --file2.sql
WebERP_Finance
  --DDL
    --file1.sql
    --file2.sql
  --DML
    --file1.sql
    --file2.sql
.
.
.
file7.sql
file9.sql
```

The files under DML and DDL folders are now called fileN.sql but in the future their name will be different.

I want to iterate through all the folders which start with "WebER*", and run a command using each one of the sql files under DDL and DML folders, but I don't want the command to run on file7.sql and file9.sql.

I tried doing some nested for loop but to no avail.

Here's what I've tried:

```
for /d %%R in (WebER*) do (
    for /r %%F (*.sql) do
       java -jar %liquibasejar% --changeLogFile=%workspace%\\SQL_Changes\\%%R\\DDL\\%%F update 
    )
```

The error I get is: `r was unexpected at this time.`

**Edit #1:**
When this stage is running:

```
stage ('Run SQL scripts') {
                    bat """
                        set liquibasejar="c:\\Program Files (x86)\\LiquiBase\\liquibase.jar"
                        set sqljdbc="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\liquibase\\sqljdbc.jar"
                        set url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName"
                        set driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"                   

                        cd %WORKSPACE%\\SQL_Changes
                        for /d %%R in (WebER*) do (
                            for /r "%%R" %%F in (*.sql) do (
                                echo "F: %%F"
                                java -jar %liquibasejar% --classpath=%sqljdbc% --url=%url%=%%R --driver=%driver% --username=%sql_user% --password=%sql_passwd% --changeLogFile=%workspace%\\SQL_Changes\\%%R\\DDL\\%%F update
                                java -jar %liquibasejar% --classpath=%sqljdbc% --url=%url%=%%R --driver=%driver% --username=%sql_user% --password=%sql_passwd% --changeLogFile=%workspace%\\SQL_Changes\\%%R\\DML\\%%F update
                            )
                        )
                    """

                }
```

That's the output from Jenkins:

```
c:\jenkins\workspace\Ensure_database_mgmt\SQL_Changes>(for /R "%R" %F in (*.sql) do (
echo "F: %F"  
 java -jar "c:\Program Files (x86)\LiquiBase\liquibase.jar" --classpath="C:\Program Files (x86)\liquibase\sqljdbc.jar" --url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName"=WebERP_Finance --driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"                   --username=**** --password=**** --changeLogFile=c:\jenkins\workspace\Ensure_database_mgmt\SQL_Changes\WebERP_Finance\DDL\%F update  
 java -jar "c:\Program Files (x86)\LiquiBase\liquibase.jar" --classpath="C:\Program Files (x86)\liquibase\sqljdbc.jar" --url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName"=WebERP_Finance --driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"                   --username=**** --password=**** --changeLogFile=c:\jenkins\workspace\Ensure_database_mgmt\SQL_Changes\WebERP_Finance\DML\%F update 
) ) 
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

You can see that the last "%%F" is not translated properly... any idea why?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43945084/deleting-folders-recursively-using-windows-batch-script/43945671) appears to have some similarities that may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it.

Batch files use the *line oriented* format, so all commands and delimiters must be complete in each line. In your case, the second `for` command needs an open parentheses, otherwise it is an *incomplete command* (and obviously, an additional closing paren), and you also forgot the `in` word.

However, your code have also a logic error. You need to specify that the second `for /r` will work *inside* each one of the folders selected by first `for /d`. This is done via an additional `pushd` command, because as user @Magoo indicate, `for /R` can not work when the starting folder is another `for` parameter.

```
for /d %%R in (WebER*) do (
    pushd "%%R"
    for /r %%F in (*.sql) do (
       java -jar %liquibasejar% --changeLogFile=%workspace%\\SQL_Changes\\%%R\\DDL\\%%F update 
    )
    popd
)
```

Comment: Sadly, `for/r` does not like a variable as the start-directoryname. PUSHD/POPD required...

Comment: @Magoo: Thanks! fixed... **`:)`**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please check Edit #1.